# Generics: Why casting with wildcard and vise versa allowed in Method Parameter Passing?

Tags: java, list, generics, jvm, object-reference

I have following code:

```
public static void swap(List<?> list) {
    swapHelper(list); //1
}

private static <E> void swapHelper(List<E> list) {
    swap(list); //2
}

{
    List<?> tW = new ArrayList<>();
    List<E> tE = new ArrayList<>();

    tW = tE; // 3
    tE = tW; // 4
}
```

In this code line 1 and 2 compiles successfully, doesn't this mean:
i can assign references of `List<?>` to that of `List<E>` and vice versa?
If so then why line number 4 does not compile.

Answer (score -2):

Both `<?>` and `<E>` are unknown types; but all `List<?>`s have elements of *some* type, so you are able to call a method whose parameter is `List<E>`, because there is some unknown type which matches it.

Note that you can't do this:

```
public static void swap(Object object, List<?> list) {
    swapHelper(object, list); // Compiler error: object not in bounds of list.
}

private static <E> void swapHelper(E object, List<E> list) {
    swap(object, list); // OK.
}
```

because you now don't know if `Object` is within the bounds of `List<?>`.

Nor can you add new non-null values to the list:

```
private static <E> void swapHelper(List<E> list) {
    list.add(new E());  // Can't create an instance of type variable.
    swap(list);
}
```

but you can add values which you take from the list, since they are known to be within the bounds of the list:

```
private static <E> void swapHelper(List<E> list) {
    list.add(list.get(0));
    swap(list);
}
```

so it is type safe to do invoke the original `swapHelper` from `swap`, since you can't cause something which is not castable to `E` (whatever that type is) to the list.

Similarly with `tW` and `tE`:

- If you assign `tW = tE`, you can't add anything to `tW` other than `null`, so you can't put `tE` in a state where it contains anything other than instances of `E`.
- If you were allowed to assign `tE = tW`, you *could* add non-null instances of `E` to `tE`. This might mean that you could add an instance of the wrong class to `tW`, potentially leading to runtime type errors. As such, this assignment is forbidden.

Remember that assigning a list doesn't cause the list to be copied: if you assign `tE = tW`, then `tE == tW`, so all changes applied to `tE` are also visible via `tW`, since they are same instance.